# there is no way to serialize parameters for sendRawtransaction, except ethereumjs-tx?

Tags: swift, xcode, ethereum, json-rpc, go-ethereum

I am making ethereum iphone application.

Currently there is no way to serialize parameters for `sendRawtransaction`, except `ethereumjs-tx`?

My development environment is Swfit 4.0 / Xcode 9.
I am using web3's JSON-RPC API in Alamofire.